# How to attach div to mouse pointer so it will work properly during scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to attach some kind of tips above buttons and show them on hover so they will appear directly aside to mouse pointer. I want to store text for those tips in data-attributes of buttons and create them dynamically using jquery. I use .pageX .pageY stuff to find coordinates of cursor, but it's working fine only in certain point of scroll.

```js
$('button').mouseenter(function (e) {
    var data = $(this).data('value');
    if(data){
        $('<div />', {
                    'class' : 'tip',
                    text : $(this).data('value'),
                    css : {
                        position: 'fixed',
                        top: e.pageY-230,
                        left: e.pageX+15
                    }
                }).appendTo(this);
}
})
.mouseleave(function () {                                              
   $('.tip', this).remove();                  
})
.mousemove(function (e) {      
    $('.tip', this).css({
        top: e.pageY-230,
        left: e.pageX+15
    });                 
})
```

```css
button {
margin: 10px;
}
.divs {
    width: 100%;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    margin: 0px;
}
.tip {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 3px 4px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    padding: 3px; 
    font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divs"></div>
    <button data-value="Per">First</button>
    <button data-value="Aspera">Second</button>
    <button data-value="Ad">Third</button><br>
    <button data-value="Astra">Yadi</button>
    <button data-value="To infinity">Yada</button>
    <button data-value="and beyond!">Bla-bla</button>
<div class="divs"></div>
```

You better watch it: http://jsfiddle.net/millerJr/ps8vf8ce/

So, how to attach those tips to pointer directly, regardless to scroll position? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "but it's working fine only in certain point of scroll."?

Comment: @ajameswolf. I meant, it puts the tip near cursor only if buttons take some certain places on the screen. Run that code snippet above and scroll until first row of buttons appear. When you hover on them - everything fine. But if you scroll once more, and hover again, tips will appear in the same place on screen, but far away from the button and cursor. I'm not native speaker, so yeah, I can be obscure sometimes, sorry about  that. Hope, it made sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `e.clientX` and `e.clientY` in this manner
`top: e.clientY+$(this).height()` and `left: e.clientX+$(this).width()/2` for bottom center of `this` element in scope. You can add anything else wrt the current element hovered upon

`e.clientX` and `e.clientY` will provide the exact mouse co-ordinates

Snippet Below

```js
$('button').mouseenter(function (e) {
    var data = $(this).data('value');
    if(data){
        $('<div />', {
                    'class' : 'tip',
                    text : $(this).data('value'),
                    css : {
                        position: 'fixed',
                        top: e.clientY+$(this).height(),
                        left: e.clientX+$(this).width()/2
                    }
                }).appendTo(this);
}
})
.mouseleave(function () {                                              
   $('.tip', this).remove();                  
})
.mousemove(function (e) {      
    $('.tip', this).css({
        top: e.clientY+$(this).height(),
        left: e.clientX+$(this).width()/2
    });                 
})
```

```css
button {
margin: 10px;
}
.divs {
    width: 100%;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    margin: 0px;
}
.tip {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 3px 4px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    padding: 3px; 
    font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divs"></div>
    <button data-value="Per">First</button>
    <button data-value="Aspera">Second</button>
    <button data-value="Ad">Third</button><br>
    <button data-value="Astra">Yadi</button>
    <button data-value="To infinity">Yada</button>
    <button data-value="and beyond!">Bla-bla</button>
<div class="divs"></div>
```